# Разные времена глаголов в одном предложении. Верно ли оно составлено?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли составлено предложение: "Он псих, что давно ненавидит жизнь и плевал на других(в переносном смысле) и на себя".  Уместно ли в таком случае, что глаголы разных временён?

Или будет вернее сказать ,"Он псих, что сломал себе напрочь жизнь и плевал на других и на себя"?

Спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант редактирования:

*Он псих, **который** давно ненавидит жизнь и **плевать хотел** на других и на себя.*

[https://phraseology.academic.ru/13676/Плевать_хотел](https://phraseology.academic.ru/13676/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB)

**Плевать хотел на кого, на что**: Прост. Пренебр. О крайнем неуважении, пренебрежении, равнодушии или презрении к кому-либо или к чему-либо. *Плевать я хотел на эти гнилые леса. Я теперь не охотник. Я рабочий человек* (Паустовский. Колхида).

Пояснение

1) Местоимение ***что*** использовано не совсем удачно, так как возможно неоднозначное понимание начала предложения: он псих, потому что ненавидит жизнь...

2) *Плевал, плевать хотел* — это фразеологические выражения, поэтому их форма не связана напрямую со временем действия.

Например, такой диалог: — Он о тебе плохого мнения. — Плевал я на  его мнение (плевать я хотел на его мнение).

Comment: прошу прощения, правильно ли я Вас понял, что употребить "что" в значении "который" будет не совсем уместно и в следующем случае: "он бесчувственный псих, что(который) давно ненавидит жизнь и плевал на других"?

Comment: Союзное слово ЧТО может использоваться для обозначения одушевленного лица,  здесь нет грамматической ошибки, но есть стилистическая неточность, так как ИМЕННО в этом предложении  не сразу понятна функция  ЧТО  (можно подумать: "сломал что" и т.д.) Вопрос № 293325  Во фразе: "Хотя, может, тот, что фермер. Или тот, что ремесленник." Правильно употребить союзное слово "что" или, все-таки, "кто"?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка: Здесь, в разговорной конструкции, уместно употребление местоимения "что".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!